# In WB Changing the texture while simulating

Tags: textures, proto, webots

How to animate the texture of a shape in a proto or wbt file used in WeBots*?

There could have been c3d but it's not implemented, and we can't add gif as images.

*WeBots is a software to simulate robots like Gazebo but with less features.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a PBR texture or image textures for your geometry in Webots , Unluckily we cannot add gif as images

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).